# Refactoring automatically source java code NOT jar

Tags: java, refactoring, obfuscation

i have a question for you all! I have a complex java program and i need to rename possibly automatically all names of classes and methods. This is done in a very good way by PRoguard but can be applied only to jar then i will have to decompile. Can do that directly on the source code?

Comment: What goal do you want to achieve with this?

Comment: I would advise against doing it directly on the source code. There would be no point really - the only people who ever get the source code would be people who have permission to edit it, in which case you wouldn't want it to be obfuscated. If they didn't need to edit the code, then they could get the jar (which would be obfuscated.)

Answer (score 3):

If by "automatically" you mean "enter a new name for a class/method and it is renamed everywhere else in the source code," then yes, you can. Any of the major Java IDEs (IntelliJ, Eclipse, etc.) have support for global renaming of classes, methods, parameters, and just about anything else you can think of.

Comment: I agree with this answer; be careful, however, around classes and methods that are loaded using reflection.